# Set initial counting value to dynamic row table

Tags: javascript

I have a table that count row dynamically `id = counter`, but the problem is the counting starts at `2` instead of `1`.
I'm not sure how can I set an initial value to it.

I also tried a dirty workaround by subtracting by `1` at first `var count = $('#table tr').length - 1;`.
Of course it didn't work, but when I remove the row by button, in descending order it works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  update_amounts();
  $(document).on('change', '.price', function() {
    update_amounts();
  });
  $(document).on('change', '.qty', function() {
    update_amounts();
  });

  function update_amounts() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    var count = $('#table tr').length;
    $('.product').each(function() {
      var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
      var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
      var amount = (qty * price)
      document.getElementById("counter").value = count;
      sum += amount;
      gtotal = sum + count;
      $(this).find('.amount').val(amount);
    });
    $('.total').val((sum).toFixed(2));
    $('.gtotal').val((gtotal).toFixed(2));
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.reminput', function() {
    var rr = $(this).closest('tr');
    rr.addClass('row-highlighted');
    if (rr.hasClass('newTR')) rr.remove();
    var count = $('#table tr').length;
    update_amounts();
  });

  $("#add_more").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $("#table tbody tr:last").clone();
    clone.addClass('newTR');
    clone.find('td.remTD input').removeClass('hidden');
    $("#table tbody").append(clone);
    var count = $('#table tr').length;
    document.getElementById("counter").value = count;
  });
  $("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($("#cart1").serialize());
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <div class="clone_row">
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" class="table table-bordered" id="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Rate (hidden)</th>
              <th>Price (CNY)</th>
              <th>Price (MYR)</th>
              <th>Item Name (ENG)</th>
              <td>
                <center> <button type="button" name="add" id="add_more" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btnadd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <div class="clone_row">
            <tr class="product">
              <td><input class="form-control qty" type="number" value="1" name="rate[]" readonly/></td>
              <td><input class="form-control price" name="pricecny[]" type="number"></td>
              <td><input class="form-control amount" type="number" name="pricemyr[]" readonly/></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="itemname[]" /></td>
              <td class="remTD">
                <center><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnremove reminput"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Subtotal</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control total" id="total" name="lblTotal" readonly required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Grand Total</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control gtotal" id="gtotal" name="txtgtotal" readonly required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Transaction Fees</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control counter" id="counter" name="txtfee" value="1" readonly required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See also, external JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ydtznfsj/1/

Comment: counter starts at 2, because it is counting the tr from thead section, try to filter by product class  var count = $('.product').length;

Comment: Also I don't see the tbody tag, here is working, take a look, https://jsfiddle.net/qek9L2dx/

Comment: tried first fix, ascending count skipped. but just checked the fiddle - i noticed that i missed the tbody. everything works fine again. thanks @lissettdm